wallet-adapter-react cannot connect on mobile?
I'm using @solana/wallet-adapter-react to connect, sign in, deposit, and withdraw with the PhantomWalletAdapter. Everything works fine on desktop, but I cannot connect on mobile browsers. Whenever I try to connect, it directs me to the Phantom Wallet's landing page. I've attempted to set autoconnect to false, but it doesn't work either.
Did you guy have face similar issues before? Please give me an idea. Thanks


Do you have a qustion? Can you please provide more context / code / environment?

@DanielPavel Updated, thanks
